# How to define common python-click options for multiple commands?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-click

In python 3.8 I want to define some click options that are common to multiple commands. I tried the following piece of code:

```
import click


@click.group()
@click.option(
    "-v",
    "--verbose",
    count=True,
    default=0,
    help="-v for DEBUG",
)
@click.option(
    "--path",
    help="Main Path.",
)
def cli():
  pass


@click.command("list")
@click.option(
    "--list-option",
    help="Special option for list command.",
)
def my_list_command(verbose, path, list_option):
    print(verbose, path, list_option)

@click.command("find")
@click.option(
    "--find-option",
    help="Special option for find command.",
)
def my_find_command(verbose, path, find_option):
    print(verbose, path, find_option)

cli.add_command(my_list_command)
cli.add_command(my_find_command)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cli()
```

But when I try to run the command

```
python script.py list
```

I get an error

```
TypeError: cli() got an unexpected keyword argument 'verbose'
```

What I want, is that the command `list` has the following three options: `verbose`, `path` and `list-option` and that the command `find` has the following three options: `verbose`, `path` and `find-option`. I do not want to define the options for `verbose` and `path` twice.

Is there a way to do this?

I also tried to use `@click.pass_context` but that does not seem to solev the issue.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The way you currently defined it it will work, but the `--verbose` option belongs to the main command group, so you'd need to call it as `python script.py --verbose list` (and `my_find_command` and `my_list_command` won't receive it as an argument, only `cli`).

To use the same option across multiple commands without repeating yourself too much, you can just assign it to a variable and then use it twice:

```
verbose_option = click.option(
    "-v",
    "--verbose",
    count=True,
    default=0,
    help="-v for DEBUG",
)

...

@click.command()
@verbose_option
def foo(verbose):
    ...

@click.command()
@verbose_option
def bar(verbose):
    ...
```

---

Unrelated, but while we're at it: There's a simpler way of grouping commands, without having to do `cli.add_command(my_find_command)`: Just use `@cli.command()` instead of `@click.command()`:

```
import click

option_verbose = click.option(
    "-v",
    "--verbose",
    count=True,
    default=0,
    help="-v for DEBUG",
)

@click.group()
def cli():
    pass


@cli.command("list")
@option_verbose
@click.option(
    "--list-option",
    help="Special option for list command.",
)
def my_list_command(verbose, list_option):
    print(verbose, list_option)

@cli.command("find")
@option_verbose
@click.option(
    "--find-option",
    help="Special option for find command.",
)
def my_find_command(verbose, list_option):
    print(verbose, list_option)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cli()
```

---

If there's *several* options you want to apply, you can define your own decorator that calls all those options on the argument:

```py
def common_options(fn):
    return click.option(
        "-v",
        "--verbose",
    )(
        click.option(
            "-n",
            "--dry-run",
        )(fn)
    )
```

Comment: Thanks - I tried to use that in combination with command group, but it does not work for some reason: https://pastebin.com/V9qz3Vfq

Comment: It seems that `@cli.command()` does not work

Comment: You misunderstand me: You can just remove those lines and _instead_ use `@cli.command()` where you now use `@click.command`. See my last edit.

Comment: @L3viathan your solution works great! However, if I have a bunch of "common" options to share amongst sub-commands; is there a cleaner way instead of assigning each option to a separate variable and then adding bunch of @<that variable> to all my sub commands?

Comment: @shikhanshu You can just define a decorator that applies those two decorators. I've added an example.